# Keep the distinct rows among groups based on a column in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidy

My data frame looks like this

```
df <- data.frame(gene=c("A","B","C","A","B","D"), 
                 origin=rep(c("old","new"),each=3),
                 value=sample(rnorm(10,2),6))

  gene origin     value
1    A    old 1.5566908
2    B    old 1.3000358
3    C    old 0.7668213
4    A    new 2.5274712
5    B    new 2.2434525
6    D    new 2.0758326
```

I want to keep the distinct genes between the groups of old and new in the origin column.
I want my data to look like this

```
  gene origin     value
3    C    old 0.7668213
6    D    new 2.0758326
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grouped by 'gene', look for the number of distinct 'origin' which is 1 in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      group_by(gene) %>%
      filter(n_distinct(origin) == 1) %>%
      ungroup
```